# Showing the image in tooltip

Tags: jquery, html, tooltip

i am using [tipsy plugin](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/)

---

[image]

---

I want to show an image of a **User** if someone hover's his link.Now the link have an **id** by which an image is stored in server. so for example if **id** is **4** then image would be **4.jpg** so I used this code to show the tool tip as this :

```
$('.tipsy').tipsy({
        html: true,
        gravity : 'e',
        title: function() {
            var i=0;
            alert(++i + "   first");
            var imgPath='<img height="50" width="50" src="dp/' + $(this).attr('id') + '.jpg" />';
            try{
                imgPath=$(imgPath).error(function() {
                    alert(++i + "  middle");
                    //imgPath='<img height="50" width="50" src="dp/no-image.jpg" />';
                });
            }catch(err){
                alert('inside catch');
            }
            alert(++i + "   last");
            return imgPath; 
        }
    });
```

But **imgPath** never comes **<img height="50" width="50" src="dp/no-image.jpg" />** But technically speaking it would take the value of **noimage.jpg** if **error** is there but every time it shows me the img with src as **<id>.jpg**

Also one more thing I noticed this .....the sequence when no error is there is :

1. alert(++i + "   first");
2. alert(++i + "   last");

   and the sequence when error is there is :

   1. alert(++i + "   first");
   2. alert(++i + "   last");
   3. alert(++i + "   middle");

which is wrong because **middle** alert come in between **first** and **last**

Comment: Your imgPath is a HTML string. Why would you try to put that into a jQUery object?

Comment: because i want to know whether that image exists in server or not......so that's why put it into Jquery object to call `error()`

Comment: OK, I see. Did you try removing the alerts, and changing them to console.log()? Sometimes alerts can cause strange sync problems

Comment: its FIRST, LAST, MIDDLE the same sequence that's the problem because LAST executes before MIDDLE due to which **imgPath** is not updated

Answer (score 1):

I really don't no why exception is not being caught. But for any dynamic content on tooltip you can try these plugins :

http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/

http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/

Hopes it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your error function seems to be called asynchronously for some reason. I am not sure why this is happening, probably it might be in jquery docs, but what you can do is force synchronous check by using ajax() function

```
alert("first");
var imgPath; //not setting imgPath here
        try{ 
            //using ajax() instead of earlier code
            $.ajax({
                url: 'dp/' + $(this).attr('id') + '.jpg', //might need to give absolute path instead of relative one
                type: 'get',
                async:false, //making sync call to ensure this code is executed
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    imgPath='no-image.jpg'; //if image doesnt exists then set no-image
                    alert("middle-error");
                },
                success: function(data){
                    imgPath='dp/' + $(this).attr('id') + '.jpg'; //succes -set required                    
                    alert("middle-success");
                }
            });
        }catch(err){ 
            alert('inside catch'); 
        } 
alert(" last");
```

What we are doing here is checking if the image e.g. dp/4.jpg exists on server. we are also forcing `sync` call this time by setting `async:false`

Comment: try alerting $(this).attr('src') inside error function See what it returns

Comment: it returns what I want but problem is the calling sequence FIRST LAST MIDDLE that's the main problem

Comment: well the error function seems to run asynchronously for some reason. My above code does not holds true in that case. You will need to somehow force execution of try block synchronously. I will try to find the answer later when i am back from meeting. hope you get the answer before that :)

Comment: i have updated my answer. I am using synchronous ajax() call instead of error function to check if image exists on server.